# Footer in jquery mobile popup not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically add an external popup with a title and a footer, with jquery mobile, but the footer moves to the page instead of staying in the popup div ...
Is it a bug from a jquery mobile? How can I solve it?

```
 var p=$("<div />").appendTo(document.body);
 $("<div />").attr("data-role", "header").appendTo(p).html("<h1>title</h1>");
 $("<div />").addClass("ui-content").text("content").appendTo(p);
 $("<div />").attr("data-role", "footer").appendTo(p).html("<h1>footer</h1>");
 p.enhanceWithin().popup({"positionTo":"window", "theme":"a"});
 p.popup("open");
```

here is the fiddle  [http://jsfiddle.net/*stax*/y9Lsqmax/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/_stax_/y9Lsqmax/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the `footer` is parented with the `page`, I strongly believe because it can accommodate a `navbar` or a similar navigation system, or may be `eyternal`, and moreover it can be positioned at the very bottom of the screen, by using `position: fixed`. So, IMHO, it is simply not meant to be placed inside a `popup`.

BUT: You can style a `div` inside the `popup` as it looks as `footer`. Of course, it won't support all the options documented here: [jQuery Mobile Toolbar](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar/) .

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
  var p = $('<div id="popup"/>').appendTo(document.body);
  $('<div class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit"/>').html('<h4 class="ui-title">Title</h4>').appendTo(p);
  $('<div class="ui-content"/>').text("content").appendTo(p);
  $('<div class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit"/>').html('<h4 class="ui-title">Popup footer</h4>').appendTo(p);
  p.popup({"positionTo":"window", "theme":"a", "overlayTheme":"a"});

  $("#popup").popup("open");
});
```

Comment: ok you're right ! it's more about getting some footer style in the popup than having a page footer behavior... this explain the framework enhancement that automagically move the footer marked with data-role footer from the popup, to the page. Thanks!